# SQL 2005 Express: How to get those performance reports?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How do get go about being able to view those performance reports on **SQL Server 2005 Express Edition**; you know, these things (with the charts and bar graphs):

[image]

1. What are they called
2. What do i have to install to access to them
3. How do i access them?
4. What are the [SQL Server 2005 Performance Dashboard Reports](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=1d3a4a0d-7e0c-4730-8204-e419218c1efc&displaylang=en)
5. How does #4 differ from #1
6. When would one want to use #4 over #1

---

In SQL Server 2005 *Somethingorother* Edition, i right-click the server is "Enterprise Manager", select reports, and browse through them:

[image]

No such context menu option exists in SQL Server 2005 Express Edition.

**Note:** i try to ask the high-level question of "how to make it work", because the answer can, in turn, trigger a dozen or two other questions. (Microsoft's been good at keeping information about SQL Server secret in recent years)

Answer (score 1):

As with the other question you asked about Profiler, the issue is you're using SQL Server Management Studio Express Edition, which is a pared down version of SQL Server Management Studio. The ability to run reports is available in the full version of SQL Server Management Studio (with SQL Server 2005 I believe you have to apply SP2 to the client tools). So you'll need to have a full version of SSMS, connect to the Express edition, and run the reports.

Comment: And just to complete the answer: SSMS !Express Edition is not available for download? Also, the other question quotes Microsoft saying the Profiler *is* available; while saying nothing about these reports.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio Express *IS* available for download: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en and the feature you're talking about is only available in the full version of SQL Server Management Studio which must be installed from the SQL Server CD (Standard/Enterprise/Developer/DataCenter, but not Express). These are standard reports provided by MS. However, you can write your own custom reports, hence the reason the menu context has Reports >> Standard or Custom Reports.